# CloudFormation large responses with with AwsCustomResource AWS SDK calls (CodeArtifact getPackageVersionAsset)

Tags: aws-cdk

I've found a few questions and answers around using `AwsCustomResource` for making AWS SDK calls from within AWS CDK constructs, but nothing around use cases where the response might be large, and go over the limit of around 4KB for cfn responses.

My goal is to be able to fetch small-ish codeartifact stored assets from my CDK stack. Initially I started with calling the AWS SDK from within my CDK construct, but then realised that I would have race conditions as CDK constructs are not meant to run async code.

I then looked into using AwsCustomResource to do the `getPackageVersionAsset` SDK call for CodeArtifact, but now my issue is that the response is too large for the CFN response.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work for responses larger than a few KB.

```
const namespace = new AwsCustomResource(this, 'custom-resource', {
  onUpdate: {
    physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of('codeartifact-stored-artifact-namespace'),
    service: 'CodeArtifact',
    action: 'getPackageVersionAsset',
    parameters: {
      repository: codeartifactCoordinates.repository,
      domain: codeartifactCoordinates.domain,
      domainOwner: codeartifactCoordinates.domainOwner,
      format: codeartifactCoordinates.format,
      namespace: codeartifactCoordinates.groupId,
      package: codeartifactCoordinates.artifactId,
      packageVersion: codeartifactCoordinates.version,
      asset: `${codeartifactCoordinates.artifactId}-${codeartifactCoordinates.version}-${codeartifactCoordinates.classifier}.zip`
    }
  },
  policy: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({resources: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE})
});

const result = namespace.getResponseField('Data');
```

For comparison, this is the AWS SDK code I started with when calling the sdk with the client from my Construct:

```
const outputFile = `artifact-${crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex")}.yml`;
const file = require('fs').createWriteStream(outputFile);
const params : AWS.CodeArtifact.GetPackageVersionAssetRequest = {
    domain: codeartifactCoordinates.domain,
    domainOwner: codeartifactCoordinates.domainOwner,
    repository: codeartifactCoordinates.repository,
    format: codeartifactCoordinates.format,
    namespace: codeartifactCoordinates.groupId,
    package: codeartifactCoordinates.artifactId,
    packageVersion: codeartifactCoordinates.version,
    asset: `${codeartifactCoordinates.artifactId}-${codeartifactCoordinates.version}-${codeartifactCoordinates.classifier}.yml`
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    codeartifact
        .getPackageVersionAsset(params)
        .createReadStream()
        .on('end', () => {
            const data = fs.readFileSync(outputFile, "utf-8");
            const yamlNs = YAML.parse(data);
            return resolve(yamlNs);
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
            return reject(error);
        })
        .pipe(file)
    
});
```

Is there a better pattern for this? Or alternatively, is there a way to do the AWS SDK calls from within my Construct in a way that I can wait for the asset response call to complete and avoid race conditions?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using the nodejs **child_process** `spawnSync()` method for this. It spawns a synchronous child process from the node process that is running CDK. I run the AWS CLI in this process to talk to AWS CodeArtifact (in my specific case) and retrieve a large file asset.

Of course you can use any AWS CLI command here, just setup the CLI arguments as required.

```js
import * as fs from "fs"
import * as path from "path"
import * as crypto from "crypto"
import * as cp from 'child_process';

export interface CodeArtifactCoordinatesType {

    readonly repository: string;

    readonly domain: string;

    readonly domainOwner: string;

    readonly format: string;

    readonly groupId: string;

    readonly artifactId: string;

    readonly version: string;

    readonly classifier: string;
}

export class YourClassNameHere {
    static fromCodeArtifactCoordinates(codeartifactCoordinates: CodeArtifactCoordinatesType) : any {

        const outputFile = `${codeartifactCoordinates.artifactId}-${codeartifactCoordinates.version}-${codeartifactCoordinates.classifier}.ext`;
        var getPackageVersionAssetProcess = cp.spawnSync('aws', [
            'codeartifact',
            'get-package-version-asset',
            '--domain',
            codeartifactCoordinates.domain,
            '--domain-owner',
            codeartifactCoordinates.domainOwner,
            '--repository',
            codeartifactCoordinates.repository,
            '--format',
            codeartifactCoordinates.format,
            '--namespace',
            codeartifactCoordinates.groupId,
            '--package',
            codeartifactCoordinates.artifactId,
            '--package-version',
            codeartifactCoordinates.version,
            '--asset',
            outputFile,
            outputFile
        ], {stdio: [0, 1, 2]});

        if (getPackageVersionAssetProcess.error) {
            console.error(getPackageVersionAssetProcess.error.stack);
            throw "Error executing 'get-package-version-asset' aws cli command."
        } else if (getPackageVersionAssetProcess.stderr) {
            console.error(getPackageVersionAssetProcess.stderr);
            throw "aws codeartifact get-package-version-asset command parameters caused an error."
        } else {
            const data = fs.readFileSync(outputFile, "utf-8");
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call it as a static method. E.g.

```js
const data = YourClassNameHere.fromCodeArtifactCoordinates(codeartifactCoordinates);
```

`codeartifactCoordinates` being an object that contains the various properties from the `CodeArtifactCoordinatesType` interface of course. i.e. `repository`, `domain`, etc...